# Windows Phone 7: How to get all buttons from a window?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

how to get all buttons from a window ? (to set the IsEnabled property to false)

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate through all the controls. For example:

```
foreach (var ctrl in LayoutRoot.Children)
{
      if (ctrl is Button)
         ((Button)ctrl).IsEnabled = false;
}
```

Of course, `LayoutRoot` is the default name. You can change that to another container if you need to.

Edited to allow for recursion for nested panels (mentioned in comments).

```
private void DisableAllButtons(Panel parent)
{

    foreach (var ctrl in parent.Children)
    {

        if (ctrl is Button)
        {

            ((Button)(ctrl)).IsEnabled = false;

        }
        else
        {
             if (ctrl is Panel)
             {
                  if (((Panel)ctrl).Children.Count > 0)
                  {

                      DisableAllButtons((Panel)ctrl);

                  }
              }

         }

     }

  }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this need to be done recursively? For instance, if `LayoutRoot` contains another `Panel` which contains `Button`s.

Comment: @Praetorian: I assumed that the user just meant one container, but you're right, if that container contains another container, then it would need to be done recursively. @Tony - Do you have nested containers?

Comment: Edited answer just incase there are nested panels.

Comment: You already got my +1 before the edit, so can't have another one :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, DisableAllButtons() might sometimes work, but in general is insufficient. Here is a real-world example. (After some simplification.)

```
ListBox 
  ScrollViewer 
    Border 
      Grid 
        ScrollContentPresenter 
          ItemsPresenter 
            VirtualizingStackPanel 
              ListBoxItem 
                ContentPresenter 
                  Grid 
                    TextBlock 
                    TextBlock 
                    Button 
              ListBoxItem 
                ContentPresenter 
                  Grid 
                    TextBlock 
                    TextBlock 
                    TextBlock 
        ScrollBar
          Grid 
            Grid 
              RepeatButton 
              Thumb 
                Rectangle 
              RepeatButton
```

If you want a reliable solution, then instead of enumeration Panel children use
VisualTreeHelper class and its methods GetCildrenCount() and GetChild(). Here is the code:

```
void DisableAllButtons(FrameworkElement fe)
{
    if (fe is Button)
        ((Button)(fe)).IsEnabled = false;

    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(fe);
    for (int index = 0; index < count; ++index)
    {
        DisableAllButtons( (FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(fe, index) );
    }
}
```